# Split PHP Array into two separates arrayes

Tags: php, arrays, split

I have this array with 3 elements from below. What I want to achieve is this:

I want to separate these elements into 2 arrays - one array should keep only entries that have `pay_flag` set to 0, and the other one with `pay_flag` set to 1.

How can I do this? I'm doing a foreach but I don't know how to separate them when condition is met. Something like:

```
foreach ($mainArray as $array) {
    if ($mainArray['pay_flag'] != 0) {
        // create a separate array with entries that have 'pay_flag' 1;
    } else {
        // create a separate array with entries that have 'pay_flag' 0;
    }
}


($mainArray) [3 elements]
0:
id: (string) "1"
user_id: (null) 1
description: (null) NULL
pay_flag: (integer) 0 
reported_at: (null) NULL
created_at: (string) "2020-09-06 17:00:00"

1: 
id: (string) "1"
user_id: (null) 1
description: (null) NULL
pay_flag: (integer) 0 
reported_at: (null) NULL
created_at: (string) "2020-09-06 17:00:00"

2: 
id: (string) "1"
user_id: (null) 1
description: (null) NULL
pay_flag: (integer) 1 
reported_at: (null) NULL
created_at: (string) "2020-09-06 17:00:00"
```

Comment: You can create 2 arrays, and add the entries to it using array_push in the loop

Comment: Example code please.

Comment: _“when condition is met”_ - your condition there makes no sense to begin with. `$mainArray['pay_flag']` does not exist, the _current_ array element inside your foreach loop is accessible via `$array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `array_filter`, for example:

```
$withoutPayFlag = array_filter($mainArray, function($value)) {
        return $value['pay_flag'] === 0;
    }
);
```

The function callback makes sure only items are returned that have pay_flag in the array set to 0. You can then do this for pay_flag 1 as well, and add the results to a different array, e.g. `$withPayFlag`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$items = 
[
    [
        'name' => 'Fred',  'flag' => 0
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Wilma', 'flag' => 1
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Betty', 'flag' => 1
    ]
];

foreach($items as $item)
{
    $grouped[$item['flag']][] = $item;
}

var_export($grouped);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'Fred',
      'flag' => 0,
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'Wilma',
      'flag' => 1,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'Betty',
      'flag' => 1,
    ),
  ),
)
```

You can then access the zeros via `$grouped[0]` and the ones via `$grouped[1]` (as long as you have both types of flags).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution which based on your question, try to use the **operator [ ]** to add items to the array:

```
<?php

$mainArray = 
[
    [
        'lorem' => 'aaaa',  'pay_flag' => 0
    ],
    [
        'lorem' => 'bbbb', 'pay_flag' => 1
    ],
    [
        'lorem' => 'cccc', 'pay_flag' => 1
    ]
];

$arr1 = array();
$arr0 = array();

foreach ($mainArray as $array) {
    if ($array['pay_flag'] !== 0) {
        // create a separate array with entries that have 'pay_flag' 1;
        $arr1[] = $array;
    } else {
        // create a separate array with entries that have 'pay_flag' 0;
        $arr0[] = $array;
    }
}

print_r($arr1);  //array which contains entries that have 'pay_flag' 1
print_r($arr0);  //array which contains entries that have 'pay_flag' 0
```